# How to cast an Object (that is an Array) back to an Array (or something more generic)?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I want to have a compare method that takes two objects and return if they are equal or not.

Inside the method I distinguish between different data types to apply the proper comparison method to the objects.

The problem is, I handover two arrays (e.g. int[]) and want to use now `SequenceEqual()`, so I have to change the objects to some generic sequence/list/array that can apply `SequenceEqual()` correctly to them.

At the moment I don't now how to change the data type correctly to something generic that does that.

An `IEnumerable<object>` would have the method `SequenceEqual()`, but if I do it this way, `source` and `test` are `null`.

```
public static bool Compare(this object o1, object o2)
{
    if (o1 is Array && o2 is Array)
    {
        // special array handling
        IEnumerable<object> source = o1 as IEnumerable<object>;
        IEnumerable<object> test = o2 as IEnumerable<object>;

        // this fails now, because source and test are null.
        return source.SequenceEqual(test);
    }
    else
    {
        return o1.Equals(o2);
    }
}
```

`Compare()` is an Extension method to Object, so I do this to call it:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

a.Compare(b);
```

What do I have to do to treat the two objects, that are Arrays, as arrays so that I can use `SequenceEqual()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array` implements `IEnumerable` so you can do:

```
IEnumerable<object> source = ((IEnumerable)o1).Cast<object>();
IEnumerable<object> test = ((IEnumerable)o2).Cast<object>();
```

Comment: Wah, wah, faster than mine!

Comment: Thanks, this one passes my unit tests, so it is correct ;) (I will test further). Let me check if I understand this correctly. I create an IEnumerable with `IEnumerable<object> source` and the content is of type `object`, with `((IEnumerable)o1).Cast<object>()` I cast the object `o1` into an IEnumerable and with the following `.Cast<object>` every member of `o1` is casted to an object. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe is worth changing `if (o1 is Array && o2 is Array)` to `if (o1 is IEnumerable && o2 is IEnumerable)` so can work with `List<T>` et simil.

Comment: @stema For types that already implement `IEnumerable<object>`, such as `object[]`, but not `int[]`, `Cast<object>` simply returns the array's own implementation of `IEnumerable<object>`. Otherwise, yes, `.Cast<object>` does pretty much what you say. (If you saw my earlier comment, it contained an error in details not really important here, so I am reposting this without those details.)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another overload like this:

```
public static bool Compare<T>(this T[] o1, T[] o2)
{
    return o1.SequenceEqual(o2);
}
```

to handle arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this also looks good, but I think I can not work with an overload here, because (in the real project) I do some other things first and `a.Compare(b);` is only called on objects and not on Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cast it first to a array, then convert it to IEnumerable, so the answer is:

```
public static bool Compare(this object o1, object o2)
{
    if (o1 is Array && o2 is Array)
    {
        // special array handling
        IEnumerable<object> source = (o1 as Array).A();
        IEnumerable<object> test = (o2 as Array).A();

        // this fails now, because source and test are null.
        return source.SequenceEqual(test);
    }
    else
    {
        return o1.Equals(o2);
    }

}
public static IEnumerable<object> A(this Array a)
{
    foreach (var item in a)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```